# Disable native Next button in Qt installer framework

Tags: c++, qt, qt-installer, qscript

I have to disable standard next button, on my custom page via installscript.qs file.

I can disable my own button (that I created in .ui file) via .qs script like this: `widget.myButton.setEnabled(false);`

[This](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-buttons.html) man shows that native buttons represented as enumeration and I cannot disable them same way.

Controller Scripting manual page shows some interactions with native buttons. Like `gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton)`. I go through whole gui object man and don't found anything useful.

Qt installer framework has a native license check page with Next button logic that I need, but I have not found any samples that do it manually. (license page work because its default license page and it's logic inside framework as I understand).

Finally I [found](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizardpage.html#isComplete) isComplete() method that can be useful for me, but it is for C++ API not for qs.
So how to disable native button via installscript.qs file?

Answer (score 5):

In case someone else end ups here, I finally found a cleaner solution: a dynamic widget has a property `complete` that can be changed to enable and disable the "Next" button. Set it to `false` to disable the button.

```
Controller.prototype.DynamicMyWidgetCallback = function()
{
    var currentWidget = gui.currentPageWidget();
    if (currentWidget != null)
    {
        currentWidget.complete = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Any suggestion on how to remove the button?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution i had found is call `installer.setValue("canContinue" "false");`

Then connect page entered event using `gui.pageById(QInstaller.TargetDirectory).entered.
connect(Component.prototype.targetPageEntered);`

In `targetPageEntered` check our value:

```
Component.prototype.targetPageEntered = function () {
    if (installer.value("canContinue") != "true") {
        gui.clickButton(buttons.BackButton);
        QMessageBox.information("someid", "Installer", 
        "You must do smth to continue", QMessageBox.Ok);
    }
}
```

Of course you need to change the `installer.value` when user complete required actions.